# Dropdown Menu not displayed

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm a beginner to web development. I'm using bootstrap (3.3.7) to create a responsive web site. I created a following code to display a simple menu, but wasn't working properly.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>ICE MOBILE</title>
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
            <form>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                            <li class="active"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Home</a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></span> Menu
                                    <span class="caret"></span>
                                </a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#"> Menu-1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"> Menu-2</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>


    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

When I click "Menu" it doesn't show the dropdown menu.

What could be the reason for dropdown menu not working properly?

Comment: Are your assets in the referenced directories?

Comment: What behaviour are you expecting? What issue are you running into? Maybe read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question for clarity.

Comment: @SanchitPatiyal I had updated the problem.

Comment: @Tijmen I had updated the problem.

Comment: @OluwafemiSule yes, they are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problem I see is with your assets not locating to the right place. All I did is imported the online libraries and it is working fine. Do check your assets location.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>ICE MOBILE</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
            <form>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                            <li class="active"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Home</a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></span> Menu
                                    <span class="caret"></span>
                                </a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#"> Menu-1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"> Menu-2</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>


  
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->


</body>
</html>
```